# How can we achive the replica of databases for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, ms-access, merge-replication

I have been working in VB6 to VB.NET migration project.In VB6 project they have individual databases (access db `.mdb`) for every user now we made that to centralized database using SQL Server.

In the old application we have a `MasterDB.mdb` which is in sync with the `local.mdb`. Some times we need to sync with both the users of `local.mdb`. After a particular interval of time we need to sync with the `MasterDB.mdb`.

We need to do this in SQL Server. So, I have a done more analysis related to SQL Server. I read a MSDN forums and many articles related to replication in SQL Server ([Related Scenario](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sqlreplication/thread/aeda1871-e2f4-4202-aea0-27f89a393566)). I think that ***merge replication*** matches to my requirements.

Can anyone suggest whether I have chosen the correct replication? Do we have any environment changes to set up this replication?

Comment: Just to be clear, what is the strategy to migrate from Access to SQL Server? Separate databases, I assume? The topology of your system isn't clear from the question text.

Comment: Client wants to migrate the DB part to SQL Server also. So he wants to do the replication process in SQL Server also .

Comment: That's my question. Is there actually a need/requirement to use replication, instead of a single database across the entire application?

Answer (score 2):

To reinforce what Jon says - a single DB to which all clients connect all the time, with the schema designed accordingly, will be a much better solution.  You only need replication in a few circumstances.  One is if a client machine must be able to work while disconnected.  Another will be if there are huge latency issues between your various sites.  Replication, especially two-way merge replication, can be a huge pain - during upgrades, for example.